# No authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'Cookies'. in custom authorization filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

When I have the default `AuthorizeAttribute` in action, all works perfectly.

However, when creating a custom `Attribute` implementing `IAuthorizationFilter`, I need the user to be redirected to login page if not authenticated and this is not working.

If I set in the user not authenticated condition:

> context.Result = new ChallengeResult(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

This error is shown:

> InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is registered for
> the scheme 'Cookies'. The registered schemes are:
> Identity.Application, Identity.External, Identity.TwoFactorRememberMe,
> Identity.TwoFactorUserId, Bearer, Google, Facebook. Did you forget to
> call AddAuthentication().AddSomeAuthHandler?

This is how I added authentication:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(x =>
    {
        x.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
        x.SaveToken = true;
        x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = configuration["Modules:Authenticate:AuthJwt:Issuer"],
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = configuration["Modules:Authenticate:AuthJwt:Audience"],
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            RequireExpirationTime = false,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["Modules:Authenticate:AuthJwt:Key"] ?? string.Empty))
        };
    })
    .AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
    {
        googleOptions.ClientId = configuration["Modules:Authenticate:Google:ClientId"] ?? string.Empty;
        googleOptions.ClientSecret = configuration["Modules:Authenticate:Google:ClientSecret"] ?? string.Empty;
        googleOptions.CallbackPath = "/Security/GoogleSignIn";
    })
    .AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
    {
        facebookOptions.AppId = configuration["Modules:Authenticate:Facebook:AppId"] ?? string.Empty;
        facebookOptions.AppSecret = configuration["Modules:Authenticate:Facebook:AppSecret"] ?? string.Empty;
        facebookOptions.CallbackPath = "/Security/FacebookSignIn";
    });

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "DesytecSecurity";
    options.Cookie.Path = "/";
    options.LoginPath = "/Authenticate/Security/Login";
    options.LogoutPath = "/Authenticate/Security/Logout";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Authenticate/Security/AccessDenied";
    options.ReturnUrlParameter = "ReturnUrl";
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
});

services.AddAuthorization();
```

I know this could be solved if I add the scheme with the `services.AddAuthentication` call, however, if I use the default `AuthorizeAttribute` it redirects correctly when user is not logged in, meaning there is other way to do that.

Any help?

Comment: As the issue message said, you need to register the authentication handler for the "CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme".  Besides, from your description, you want to redirect to the login page in the custom AuthorizeAttribute's method, in this case, you can try to use the `context.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("Login", "Account", null);` or `context.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Login/Index");` to redirect to the login page in the OnAuthorization method, instead of using `context.Result = new ChallengeResult(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);`.

Comment: When using the default `AuthorizeAttribute` it works, even when I don't have that scheme configured. On the other hand, as you see, login page is `/Authenticate/Security/Login` and return parameter is set as `ReturnUrl`. All those parametes could change, so, is there a way to build the login page URL automatically? I could build it manually, for example, `new RedirectResult(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.LoginPath)` and for return url, I could append the `UrlReferrer` to set the value, but I am wondering if there is an automatic way to do it. I browsed .NET Core source but I did not find a clue.

Comment: @ZhiLv I have created the result as just `new ChallengeResult()` and it works, however, I had the problem of the target login URL. It is relative instead of absolute. For example, this is the login page where system actually redirects to: `https://localhost:44375/Personal/Authenticate/Security/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FPersonal` instead of just `https://localhost:44375/Authenticate/Security/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FPersonal`. How can I force this to be an absolute URL?

Comment: To solve the last problem, I have used `OnRedirectToLogin` event, but I don't know if this is the most elegant solution. It works, at least.